# How to make MVC Model a Singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am designing a camera viewing website for a network with multiple cameras. Right now, everything works perfectly, unless you open another tab, because that creates another instance of the model, causing problems. Is there any way to make the Model class a singleton, so that it can only be created once per camera?
The Model Class is made by the MVC framework, so Im not sure how this would work.

Right now the Controller looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Index(string IP)
{
    return View(new CameraViewModel() { IP = IP });
}
```

Is there any way to only make a new class if IP is a new one, otherwise just return the view with the previously created CameraViewModel?

Comment: a) Yes you can. b) That is a very weird thing to do.

Comment: The most obvious way to do the exact thing you are asking for would be to use `MemoryCache` and cache by the IP string passed in (with some kind of appropriate cache duration). The solution to your likely _underlying_ (i.e. real) problem is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2 .

Comment: `because that creates another instance of the model, causing problems.` What problems? Can you show us a [mcve]?

Comment: @mjwills The Model does video processing, and sends frames one by one to the client where they are displayed. If two models send images to the client, It makes the video super jittery, as it recieves 2x the frames, which is a problem

Comment: @mjwills Can you add this as a solution with some code?

Comment: Not without a [mcve] I can't.

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need a lot more context, particularly how the client receives more frames. Reload the page? Embed a video player? .... some other method? Since your CameraViewModel only takes a string, I don't see why it would need to be a singleton...

Comment: Maybe you need to split that model into two: 1) get feed from camera and process it (once per active camera) and 2) send processed frames to the client (once per client)